# Using css vars as stored in data attributes for dynamic coloring

Tags: html, css, svg, attributes

I am trying to make a SVG image using html and css. I need the colors to be quickly interchangeable by substituting different css variables. This is the set up I currently have:

```css
:root{
 --c1:#f00;
 --c2:#00f;
}
polygon{
 fill:var(attr(data-clr));
 stroke:var(attr(data-clr));
 stroke-width:1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width='100' height='100'>
 <polygon points="0,100 0,0, 100,0" data-clr="--c1"/>
 <polygon points="0,100 100,100, 100,0" data-clr="--c2"/>
</svg>
```

The expected result:
A square made up of 2 triangles, one red, one blue.

The actual result: A square made up of 2 black triangles.

Keep in mind that in the real world this will include many more polygons, and simply hardcoding the colors, then find-and-replacing won't do the trick. **Doing it with classes would lead to a lot of duplicate code/code patterns so I would like to avoid it if possible.**
<- I would need to rewrite the css polygon into a class, and then for each color in the whole svg image copy and paste that class with the correct color. Yeah no.

Comment: The problem is that `attr()` returns a string.  So you are effectively doing `fill:var("--c1");` which won't work.  There's a proposal to add a type value to `attr()`. So in the future you may be able to do `var(attr(data-clr color))`. But no browsers support that yet.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using data attributes you can use the `style` attribute like so:

```css
polygon{
 fill:var(--c1);
 stroke:var(--c2);
 stroke-width:1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width='100' height='100' style="--c2:#00f;" >
 <polygon points="0,100 0,0, 100,0" style="--c1:#f00;" />
 <polygon points="0,100 100,100, 100,0" style="--c1:#00f;" />
</svg>
```

I hope this is what you need.

## UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> that means I won't be able to use drop-in stylesheets containing the vars... Meaning if I want to change colours I'll have to do a find and replace.

In this case you can do something like this: the value --c1 is another variable: `var(--a1);` The same for --c2

```css
:root{
 --a1:#f00;
 --a2:#00f;
}


polygon{
 fill:var(--c1);
 stroke:var(--c2);
 stroke-width:1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width='100' height='100' style="--c2:#00f;" >
 <polygon points="0,100 0,0, 100,0" style="--c1:var(--a1);" />
 <polygon points="0,100 100,100, 100,0" style="--c1:var(--a2);" />
</svg>
```

Comment: that means I won't be able to use drop-in stylesheets containing the vars... Meaning if I want to change colours I'll have to do a find and replace.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the most compact way it can be done right now.